# CouchDB, Elastic Search, and River Plugin not operating correctly

Tags: couchdb, elasticsearch

I'm trying to get ElasticSearch to work, specifically with the River Plugin.  For some reason I just can't get it to work. I've included the procedure I'm using to try and do it, found [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/tutorials/2010/08/01/couchb-integration.html):

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/_all/'
```

Response:

```
{
  "ok": true,
  "acknowledged": true
}
```

This is so I know I'm working with an empty set of elasticsearch instances.

I have an existing database, called test and the river plugin has already been installed. Is there anyway to test to confirm the River Plugin is installed and running?

I issue the following command:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_river/my_index/_meta' -d '{
    "type" : "couchdb",
    "couchdb" : {
        "host" : "localhost",
        "port" : 5984,
        "db" : "my_couch_db",
        "filter" : null
    }
}'
```

my_couch_db is a real database, I see it in Futon.  There is a document in it.

Response:

```
{
  "ok": true,
  "_index": "_river",
  "_type": "my_index",
  "_id": "_meta",
  "_version": 1
}
```

Now at this point, my understanding is elasticseach should be working as I saw in the tutorial.

I try to query, just to find anything. I go to

```
 http://localhost:9200/my_couch_db/my_couch_db.
```

Response:

```
No handler found for uri [/my_couch_db/my_couch_db] and method [GET]
```

What's weird is when I go to

```
localhost:5984/my_couch_db/__changes
```

I get

```
{
  "error": "not_found",
  "reason": "missing"
}
```

Anyone have any idea what part of this I'm screwing up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I try to query, just to find anything.
>   I go to
>
> `http://localhost:9200/my_couch_db/my_couch_db.`

try adding `/_search` (w/ optional `?pretty=true`) at the end of your curl -XGET like so:

```
C:\>curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/my_couch_db/my_couch_db/_search?pretty=true"
{
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 10,
    "successful": 10,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my_couch_db",
        "_type": "my_couch_db",
        "_id": "a2b52647416f2fc27684dacf52001b7b",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "_rev": "1-5e4efe372810958ed636d2385bf8a36d",
          "_id": "a2b52647416f2fc27684dacf52001b7b",
          "test": "hello"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

> What's weird is when I go to
>   localhost:5984/my_couch_db/__changes
>
> I get `{"error":"not_found","reason":"missing"}`

try removing one of the underscores from your `__changes` and that should work like so:

```
C:\>curl -XGET "http://localhost:5984/my_couch_db/_changes"
{
  "results": [
    {
      "seq": 1,
      "id": "a2b52647416f2fc27684dacf52001b7b",
      "changes": [
        {
          "rev": "1-5e4efe372810958ed636d2385bf8a36d"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "last_seq": 1
}
```